# Subdivision Surface doesn't affect some parts of the mesh

Tags: subdivision-surface

I'm learning blender for about 2 months, and I'm having a trouble with the subdivision surface modifier. Some parts of the mesh aren't affected by the modifierenter image description here
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I click on smooth shading again, this bug goes away.

Comment: It's not a bug nor *Subdivision Surface* affecting only part of the mesh. You mesh was not shaded as *Smooth* all over, some parts of it had *Flat Shaded* areas. You can control which parts are shaded as flat or as smooth in edit mode, or you can apply shading to the whole object in object mode.